# Is there any way to connect just a USB flash drive to the monitor and run a video on HP L1950g monitors without any PC connected?

Tags: display, usb-flash-drive

I got a bunch of the HP L1950g monitors that I am trying to use for an art project. Is there any way to connect just a USB flash drive to the monitor and run a video on the monitor without any problem PC connected?

There are two USB type A ports which are powered when I insert the thumb drive but no signal. There is also a USB type B port but I don't think they are powered? Other than that just the VGA connector.

Basically I'd like to put ten of these monitors on the wall and stick ten thumb drives into them and play ten videos without using any PC.

Comment: I have seen a monitor like this. The monitor has to be specifically made to run from USB.  Any old monitor will not.  I looked for your monitor and could not see a way to do that

Comment: Even if it could do this, how would it know what to play?

Comment: Monitors for this task include software to run the package on the USB key,

Comment: Monitors are dumb screens for "monitoring" things from a computer. You want a (smart) TV.

Answer (score 4):

Most aged monitors do include an USB-HUB (v1.0 or 2.0) with one USB-B input and two USB-A outputs. But they are not connected to the monitor in any special way except for powering. You can use them to connect two input devices like mouse and keyboard, but they are not connected to the monitor's display input signal.

Having a look at the [specifications](https://www.manualpdf.in/hp/l1950g/specifications)

> USB Type-A downstream ports quantity  2
> USB hub version   2.0

this monitor seems to have an USB-2.0-HUB. But no display interface is mentioned.
So the answer appears to be: NO! Sorry.

Comment: It's not like it's not possible though, right?  I haven't ever looked, but I presume there *should* be some sort of portable solution on the market involving some rendering device you can daisy-chain/dongle onto a display port?

Comment: "*I presume there should be some sort of portable solution on the market involving some rendering device you can daisy-chain/dongle onto a display port?*" - Yes, they are called laptop computers and SBCs.

Comment: I see (at least) two approaches to this situation: 1. Either use a tiny PC board like Raspberry Pi Nano or sth. with some HDMI/DVI adapter output for each monitor. Or 2. Use one (Triple/Quad?) SLI system with several PCIe-x16 ports with cheap graphic cards that can support 3 or more digital outputs (maybe using adapter cables for HDMI and DP). In your case I would prefer the second approach. It would be far easier to realize and to manage.

Comment: I had a look at eBay and an old (LGA 2011) Quad-SLI board is about 90 bucks. Then choose 4 graphic cards and you have 8 to 16 digital outputs - means monitors to connect. I tested it with 8 VLC video instances on 4 monitors with an 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-11600K @ 3.90GHz and [this is the usage result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFu3l.jpg). So it's hard to tell if an old computer suffices for this kind of video load. I guess it depends on the kind of offloading to the graphic cards, but I don't know...